# Excel CountIf Equation

Tags: excel-formula

This question seems a little simple for this forum but I will ask it anyway.

I want to use **any function** in Excel to use either

1) calculate height `(H) (E26) X width (W) (E27)` to calculate an area OR

2) to allow a user to enter the area `(F26)` directly.

I am trying to give a user **an option** and then use this **area value** elsewhere in a much larger calculation.

Put simple, if the user uses method 1, an equation would then ignore method 2 to return the area total, and visa verse.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F26),E26*E27,F26*E27)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks W_O_L_F. ISBLANK seems the way to go, i just need to return either the sum H X W OR the area, not both. That above seems to add H X W + Area.

Comment: if F26 isblank then it will multiply E26*E27. If a value is entered in F26 it will multiply F26*E27. How would you Sum E26*E27 ? I am afraid I do not understand.